# Sentry Raven inside Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, sentry, raven

I am making a Firefox Extension and I want to log the errors/messages/exceptions produced by the extension code using Sentry.

I tried the JavsScript Raven client but I guess its not really made to live inside the "Content" context.

The error I get is: `message = "debug" is read-only`, but my actual question is, how do I go about integrating Sentry in a Firefox Addon?

PS: No, this wont go into general distribution, my api keys are safe.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was just to omit calling `.install()` and just use the error/message reporting.

There will be no automatic catching and source code but it works for my purposes.